# Script for creating a hierarchy of directories

Tags: python, directory

This script creates a hierarchy of directories.  Is this a good approach or can it be made better? I am mainly concerned with maintainability here, not efficiency. Suppose I wanted to add more directories to this hierarchy.  Would this structure of the script make it easier to do?

**Hierarchy**

```
./project_euler
    ./001_050
    ./051_100
    ...
    ./401_450
./codechef
    ./easy
    ./medium
    ./hard
./spoj
./functions
./utilities
```

**The script**

```
import os

TOP = ['project_euler', 'codechef', 'spoj', 'functions',
       'utilities']
CODECHEF = ['easy', 'medium', 'hard']

def safe_make_folder(i):
    '''Makes a folder if not present'''
    try:  
        os.mkdir(i)
    except:
        pass

def make_top_level(top):
    for i in top:
        safe_make_folder(i)

def make_euler_folders(highest):
    def folder_names():
        '''Generates strings of the format 001_050 with
        the 2nd number given by the function argument'''
        for i in range(1,highest, 50):
            yield (
                'project_euler' + os.sep +
                str(i).zfill(3) + '_' + str(i + 49).zfill(3)
                )

    for i in folder_names():
        safe_make_folder(i)

def make_codechef_folders(codechef):
    for i in codechef:
        safe_make_folder('codechef' + os.sep + i)

def main():
    make_top_level(TOP)
    make_euler_folders(450)
    make_codechef_folders(CODECHEF)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: PEP 8 advices lower case for local variables.

Comment: @Josay HIGHEST is constant, but not defined at the module level. PEP8: `Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL.`

Comment: @Lstor said that global variables are code-smell so I thought to make them local variables(which are constants so I used capital letters). What would be the correct design decision here?

Comment: @Josay Please see the above

Comment: @Anthon Please see the above comment.

Comment: Since Python doesn't have real constants, the convention is to use all uppercase (+underscore) for the variable name, make it global and treat it as read-only. It would be inappropriate to assign a value to the global 'constant' somewhere else. Look e.g. at the os.py module that comes with Python. It has `SEEK_SET = 0` at the module level and no smell is involved because it is used as a constant.

Comment: @Anthon Updated the code. How about now? Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: @AseemBansal Looks good to me, I would leave it like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the things I would do is remove the double occurrence of the strings `'project_euler'` and `'codechef'`. If you ever have to change one of these in `TOP`, you are bound to miss the repetition in the functions.

You should at least use `TOP[0]` in `make_euler_folders()` and `TOP[1]` in `make_codechef_folders`. A better approach however would be to take both definitions out of `TOP` and change `def safe_make_folder()`:

```
TOP = ['spoj', 'functions', 'utilities']

def safe_make_folder(i):
    '''Makes a folder (and its parents) if not present'''
    try:  
        os.makedirs(i)
    except:
        pass
```

The standard function [`os.makedirs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) creates the `'project_euler'` resp. 
'codechef', as the first subdirectory of each is created.

---

The other is that I would create the directory names using [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) (as it prevents e.g. the mistake of providing double path separators), in combination with [standard string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to get the leading zeros on the subfolder names:

```
os.path.join('project_euler', '{:03}_{:03}'.format(i, i+49))
```

the `{:03}` gives a 3 character wide field with leading zeros. @Josay improvemed function would then become:

```
def make_euler_folders(highest):
    for i in (os.path.join('project_euler', '{:03}_{:03}'.format(i, i+49)) \
       for i in range(1,highest, 50)):
        safe_make_folder(i)
```

And the other function would become:

```
def make_codechef_folders(codechef):
    for i in codechef:
        safe_make_folder(os.path.join('codechef', i))
```

Comment: Updated the code. Any other suggestions?

Comment: move the constant `HIGHEST` to the module level and make it a somewhat more descriptive name (HIGHEST_EXERSIZE_NUMBER ?)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite convinced that a python script is required here as a shell one-liner would probably do the trick (`mkdir -p codechef/{easy,medium,hard} spoj utilities` would be a good starting point).

Your python code could be improved by using [Generator Expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) :

```
def make_euler_folders(highest):
    def folder_names():
        '''Generates strings of the format 001_050 with
        the 2nd number given by the function argument'''
        for i in range(1,highest, 50):
            yield (
                'project_euler' + os.sep +
                str(i).zfill(3) + '_' + str(i + 49).zfill(3)
                )

    for i in folder_names():
        safe_make_folder(i)
```

would become

```
def make_euler_folders(highest):
    def folder_names():
        '''Generates strings of the format 001_050 with
        the 2nd number given by the function argument'''
        return ('project_euler' + os.sep + str(i).zfill(3) + '_' + str(i + 49).zfill(3) for i in range(1,highest, 50))

    for i in folder_names():
        safe_make_folder(i)
```

which is then nothing but :

```
def make_euler_folders(highest):
    for i in ('project_euler' + os.sep + str(i).zfill(3) + '_' + str(i + 49).zfill(3) for i in range(1,highest, 50)):
        safe_make_folder(i)
```

Comment: I used Python because I am on Windows.

Comment: Anything about use of global variables? Should I pass them or not? Best practice about that?

Comment: You should pass them. Global variables is a code smell, and leads to tighter coupling (which is bad).

Comment: Also, you should probably check your usage of literal strings as some of them are defined twice ('project_euler', 'codechef').

Comment: @Josay Is it better now?